# Access calculations across records

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with two dates in each record. I need to calculate the time between the second date on the first row and the first date on the second row. Is this possible in access?

1/23/15        1/24/15

1/27/15        1/28/15

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure how you would be using the information.  You would be using the DateDiff function.  For an example go to your immediate window on your VBA screen within Access and type

```
Msgbox Cstr(DateDiff("n","1/23/15","1/24/15"))
```

You should see a message saying 1440, as it is measured in minutes.  To adjust it for how you want to use it just visit http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/index.php a website I highly recommend bookmarking.